# CSS backdrop-filter transparent blur with smooth edges

Tags: css

Currently I have this css which simply creates a transparent blur effect:

```
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
position: absolute;
background-color: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.7);
-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
```

The problem is that this results in a hard border edge. What I need is to have a soft / fading top border with the transparency intact.

A similar question was made here but it's for Flutter and not CSS:
[How to clip the BackdropFilter with smooth edges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58878011/how-to-clip-the-backdropfilter-with-smooth-edges)

My question is, how can I have a smooth / fading top border whilst keeping the transparency blur effect intact? This will be used for a fixed mobile footer that will scroll along, so I can't use a placeholder image.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found the answer?

Comment: No, I had to use a transparent gradient overlay with a darkened footer area to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in css but I think box-shadow property make the edges soft.

```
box-shadow: 0px -2px 2px rgba(34,34,34,0.6);
```

This will make a blurry top edge you can reduce the transparency level as per your need.

Comment: I've tried adding a box shadow directly to the target element but the problem is that the box shadow doesn't have the blur effect, only a transparent box shadow.